# Loop in Related Posts Wordpress

Tags: loop

I use this script to display related posts:

```
<!-- Related Posts START-->
<?php 
    $query = get_max_related_posts();
    if ( $query ) {
?>
<div class="td_block_wrap td_block_7 td_block_widget td_uid_3_5de39f94df644_rand td-pb-border-top td_block_template_1">
    <h4 class="block-title">
        <span class="td-pulldown-size">Berita Terkait</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="td_block_inner">
        <div class="td-block-row">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="td-block-span6">
                <div class="td_module_6 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack">
                    <div class="td-module-thumb">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="td-image-wrap" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,75) ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-details">
                        <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- Related Posts END -->
```

The script displays html like this:

```
<div class="td_block_inner">
  <div class="td-block-row">
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get my related posts script to display html like this:

```
<div class="td_block_inner">
  <div class="td-block-row">
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="td-block-row">
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="td-block-row">
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
    <div class="td-block-span6">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this condition. This will display the code as you expected.

```
    <!-- Related Posts START-->
<?php 
    $query = get_max_related_posts();
    if ( $query ) {
    $i=1;
?>
<div class="td_block_wrap td_block_7 td_block_widget td_uid_3_5de39f94df644_rand td-pb-border-top td_block_template_1">
    <h4 class="block-title">
        <span class="td-pulldown-size">Berita Terkait</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="td_block_inner">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); 
            if($i%2!=0){?>
                <div class="td-block-row"><?php
            }?>
            <div class="td-block-span6">
                <div class="td_module_6 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack">
                    <div class="td-module-thumb">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="td-image-wrap" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,75) ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-details">
                        <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><?php
            if($i%2==0){ ?>
                </div><?php
            }
            $i++;
        } wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- Related Posts END -->
```

Comment: Hi @Gopalakrishnan18 This code does not work. This makes my page blank.

Comment: Now try it. I made a silly mistake sorry for that.

Comment: This time it worked @Gopalakrishnan18 , but the html layout was not what was expected.
screenshoot: [link](https://prnt.sc/q5e3lr)

Comment: Now try it, i have changed the code's condition @Renomu Reza

Comment: Well this works and is as expected. Thank you very much @Gopalakrishnan18 I really appreciate.

Comment: Thank for your appreciation, thanks a lot